# how to change the user permission of files downloaded by deluge-web?

Tags: file-permissions, bittorrent, deluge

I have a headless server running deluge to download some torrent files; everything works fine, the only problem is that the files downloaded by deluge end up in the system as root, it makes things a little bit harder to manage via ssh since I have to enter as root all the time if I wanna change folder/rename/etc; it would be much better if the files were accessible to edit using my regular non-root user account.
I kind of have a basic understanding of the chmod command but I don't feel confident to do it completely by myself, I would appreciate some help
thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to run deluge as a non root user not deluge-web.
You dont say what system you have it setup on or how you are starting deluge,
there are some good guides here [user guide/service Deluge.](http://dev.deluge-torrent.org/wiki/UserGuide/Service)
on running it as a spefic user which will solve your problem of file permissions.

Comment: Link-only answers are not acceptable.  If the guides are good, cite and quote them, otherwise going to assume your just advertising the site

Comment: the guides are system spefic and as the system has not been stated how can i paste an answer as there are 3 examples.

Comment: but hanks for the down vote